# Struggling to regenerate the new signing URL for docusign

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to implement the DocuSign embedded signing feature in our web app. I have been able to implement the general flow in the app as follows:

- The user creates an envelope and sends it to all the signers.
- The recipients from their account can click on the signing link in order to sign the documents.

The key problem that I am facing here is that the signing link expires after 5 minutes.

As per the DocuSign documentation, I have tried to regenerate the signing URL as below:

```py
from docusign_esign import ApiClient, EnvelopesApi, RecipientViewRequest

def generate_new_signing_url(request, document_signer):
    api_client = ApiClient()
    api_client.host = DOCUSIGN_URL
    api_client.set_default_header("Authorization", "Bearer " + ACCESS_TOKEN)
    #ACCESS_TOKEN is retrieved from the session variable

    envelope_api = EnvelopesApi(api_client)

    recipient_view_request = RecipientViewRequest(
        authentication_method='None',
        client_user_id=CLIENT_USER_ID,
        recipient_id=RECIPIENT_ID,
        return_url=RETURN_URL,
        user_name=FULL_NAME,
        email=EMAIL
    )

    response = envelope_api.create_recipient_view(ACCOUNT_ID, 
     ENVELOP_ID,recipient_view_request=recipient_view_request)
    # We store the ENVELOP_ID in the database when it's created for the first time and use it to regenerate the URL

    return response.url
```

The key problem is that the above code only works when this code is called by the original creator and not by the signers. Whereas the ideal situation should be that when the link is expired on the signer's end they should be given with a new URL to sign the document.

Has anyone faced a similar problem? Please help.

Comment: are you using embedded signing or remote signing? the url you generate is used how? are the users get an email with a link?

Comment: I am using embedded signing. We notify the users within the application to sign the URL and after signing they are redirected back to the application and we record the response.

Comment: sorry, I'm still confused. Do you give the embedded signing urls to the user? or is it generated inside the app in real time and the user doesn't even have to know about it? It would seem odd you need to deal with a url expiring if you create it in real time

Comment: Technically, we generate the URL and give them. It doesn't happen in realtime so when URL is older than 5 mins, it expires and there is no way for the signers to create a new URL.

Comment: how do you "give them" is what I'm curious about?

Comment: So we store it in the database and show them the link when they log in.

Comment: got it. I would recommend to generate the link when they log in. Larry has a good explanation on how to do this below.

Answer (score 0):

The signing ceremony url, as you've noted, is only good for 5 minutes. Therefore it must be generated immediately before the signer's browser is redirected to the signing ceremony url.

You should not provide the signing ceremony url to a signer to click on. Instead, you should always:

1. Obtain the signing ceremony url from DocuSign
2. Redirect the signer's browser to the url

### Delayed embedded signing ceremonies

1. Create the envelope for one or more embedded signers. (set the clientUserId attributes for the recipients)
2. In your own secure database, create a row for each of the delayed signers:

   Columns:

   1. envelopeId
   2. recipient's name
   3. recipient's email
   4. recipient's clientUserId
   5. guid (unique identifier for this signer and this envelope)
3. Send the guid to the signer who will later be using the embedded signing ceremony. Use it as a query parameter. Eg: myapp.company.com?signingguid=1234

(Later)

1. The signer will click on the url
2. Your app will look up the guid in its table
3. Your app uses the attributes of the table to request the signing ceremony url from DocuSign
4. Your app redirects the signer's browser to the signing ceremony url.
5. The signer signs and the signer is re-directed back to your app afterwards.
6. Done!

The access token that your app uses to create the signing ceremony url might need to represent the sender of the envelope (I'm not sure), or an admin. Either way, your app can use the JWT Grant flow to impersonate that DocuSign user.

The signers themselves do NOT need DocuSign user accounts.

#### Information security

1. Use a guid or other random string in the url you send your signers. You do not want those urls to be guessable!
2. Think about how you will authenticate the identity of the signers. You can have DocuSign require additional information as part of the signing ceremony, or you can check your app's session info to ensure that the signer is also authenticated (logged in) to your application.

Comment: I am going to try this approach. Can you please give me some pointers in the official document to see if a signer can request for the signing URL from their access token?